# Ansible: How to extract values from a dictionary of lists

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to fetch the values from list of dict but unable to get the exact output, which is required

Using Linux server with installed versions of ansible 2.7.5 & jinja2 2.7.2 .

**The below one is the list of dict value.**

```
DOMAIN_GROUPS_ASSIGNMENT:


CACHE01:
    - domain_group: DG1
      is_active: true
    - domain_group: DG2
      is_active: true
    - domain_group: DG3
      is_active: true
  CACHE02:
    - domain_group: DG4
      is_active: true
    - domain_group: DG5
      is_active: true
    - domain_group: DG6
      is_active: true

  SCACHE01:
    - domain_group: DG1
      is_active: false
    - domain_group: DG2
      is_active: false
    - domain_group: DG3
      is_active: true
  SCACHE02:
    - domain_group: DG4
      is_active: false
    - domain_group: DG5
      is_active: false
    - domain_group: DG6
      is_active: false
```

So far trying with the below code:

```
- debug:
      msg: "KEY: {{ item.key }}, VALUE: {{ item.value }}"
    loop: "{{ lookup('dict', DOMAIN_GROUPS_ASSIGNMENT) }}"
```

**Output which I'm getting is:**

```
TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************************************
task path: /u02/netcracker/reir1015_test/singlesite/test.yml:7
Friday 31 May 2019  08:54:59 -0400 (0:00:00.058)       0:00:00.897 ************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': u'CACHE01', 'value': [{u'is_active': True, u'domain_group': u'DG1'}, {u'is_active': True, u'domain_group': u'DG2'}, {u'is_active': True, u'domain_group': u'DG3'}]}) => {}

MSG:

KEY: CACHE01, VALUE: [{u'domain_group': u'DG1', u'is_active': True}, {u'domain_group': u'DG2', u'is_active': True}, {u'domain_group': u'DG3', u'is_active': True}]

ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': u'SCACHE02', 'value': [{u'is_active': False, u'domain_group': u'DG4'}, {u'is_active': False, u'domain_group': u'DG5'}, {u'is_active': False, u'domain_group': u'DG6'}]}) => {}

MSG:

KEY: SCACHE02, VALUE: [{u'domain_group': u'DG4', u'is_active': False}, {u'domain_group': u'DG5', u'is_active': False}, {u'domain_group': u'DG6', u'is_active': False}]

ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': u'SCACHE01', 'value': [{u'is_active': False, u'domain_group': u'DG1'}, {u'is_active': False, u'domain_group': u'DG2'}, {u'is_active': True, u'domain_group': u'DG3'}]}) => {}

MSG:

KEY: SCACHE01, VALUE: [{u'domain_group': u'DG1', u'is_active': False}, {u'domain_group': u'DG2', u'is_active': False}, {u'domain_group': u'DG3', u'is_active': True}]

ok: [localhost] => (item={'key': u'CACHE02', 'value': [{u'is_active': True, u'domain_group': u'DG4'}, {u'is_active': True, u'domain_group': u'DG5'}, {u'is_active': True, u'domain_group': u'DG6'}]}) => {}

MSG:

KEY: CACHE02, VALUE: [{u'domain_group': u'DG4', u'is_active': True}, {u'domain_group': u'DG5', u'is_active': True}, {u'domain_group': u'DG6', u'is_active': True}]
```

**Required output:**

Result should be in dict format and should be stored in one variable.

I expect something like below in list or dict format:

**CACHE01: True ,CACHE02: True, SCACHE01:False, SCACHE02: False**

The above values should get stored in one variable.

Comment: Hi ireni. Could you provide the output you are currently receiving. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, Updated the output in question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select the right `value` for your result:

```
tasks:
- name: DEBUG
  debug:
    msg: 'KEY: {{ item.key }}, VALUE: {{ item.value.0.is_active }}'
  loop: '{{ lookup("dict", DOMAIN_GROUPS_ASSIGNMENT) }}'
```

Comment: Hi JGK,
Thank you so much for your quick support.

Answer (score 5):

**update**

The expression

```yaml
  domain_groups: |
    {% filter from_yaml %}
    {% for d,g in DOMAIN_GROUPS_ASSIGNMENT.items() %}
    {{ d }}: {{ g|map(attribute='is_active') is all }}
    {% endfor %}
    {% endfilter %}
```

gives

```yaml
  domain_groups:
    CACHE01: true
    CACHE02: true
    SCACHE01: false
    SCACHE02: false
```

---

Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    DOMAIN_GROUPS_ASSIGNMENT:
      CACHE01:
      - {domain_group: DG1, is_active: true}
      - {domain_group: DG2, is_active: true}
      - {domain_group: DG3, is_active: true}
      CACHE02:
      - {domain_group: DG4, is_active: true}
      - {domain_group: DG5, is_active: true}
      - {domain_group: DG6, is_active: true}
      SCACHE01:
      - {domain_group: DG1, is_active: false}
      - {domain_group: DG2, is_active: false}
      - {domain_group: DG3, is_active: true}
      SCACHE02:
      - {domain_group: DG4, is_active: false}
      - {domain_group: DG5, is_active: false}
      - {domain_group: DG6, is_active: false}

    domain_groups: |
      {% filter from_yaml %}
      {% for d,g in DOMAIN_GROUPS_ASSIGNMENT.items() %}
      {{ d }}: {{ g|map(attribute='is_active') is all }}
      {% endfor %}
      {% endfilter %}

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: domain_groups
```

---

The task below

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.key }} {{ item.value|json_query('[].is_active') }}"
      loop: "{{ DOMAIN_GROUPS_ASSIGNMENT|dict2items }}"
```

gives:

```yaml
  msg: CACHE01 [True, True, True]
  msg: CACHE02 [True, True, True]
  msg: SCACHE01 [False, False, True]
  msg: SCACHE02 [False, False, False]
```

The filter *map*, instead of *json_query*, gives the same result

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.key }} {{ item.value|map(attribute='is_active')|list }}"
      loop: "{{ DOMAIN_GROUPS_ASSIGNMENT|dict2items }}"
```

---

**(In Ansible 2.3. and lower)**
To combine the logical values let's create filter_plugins/bool_utils.py
with 2 filters *bool_and* and *bool_or* which apply Python functions *all(list)* and *any(list)* respectively

```py
    shell> cat filter_plugins/bool_utils.py
    def bool_and(h):
        return all(h)
    def bool_or(h):
        return any(h)
    class FilterModule(object):
        ''' utility filters for operating on list of Boolean '''
        def filters(self):
            return {
                'bool_and' : bool_and,
                'bool_or' : bool_or,
            }
```

The task below with the filter *bool_and*

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.key }} {{ item.value|json_query('[].is_active')
                                          |bool_and }}"
      loop: "{{ DOMAIN_GROUPS_ASSIGNMENT|dict2items }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: CACHE01 True
  msg: CACHE02 True
  msg: SCACHE01 False
  msg: SCACHE02 False
```

The task below creates the list *status*

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        status: "{{ status|default([]) +
                    [{item.key: item.value|json_query('[].is_active')
                                          |bool_and}] }}"
      loop: "{{ DOMAIN_GROUPS_ASSIGNMENT|dict2items }}"
    - debug:
        var: status
```

gives

```yaml
  status:
  - CACHE01: true
  - CACHE02: true
  - SCACHE01: false
  - SCACHE02: false
```

---

**(In Ansible 2.4. and later)** There are tests [*any*, *all*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-if-a-list-value-is-true) available. The task below gives the same results

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.key }} {{ item.value|json_query('[].is_active') is all }}"
      loop: "{{ DOMAIN_GROUPS_ASSIGNMENT|dict2items }}
```

Comment: Hi Vladmir,
Thank you so much for your quick support.