# How to insert values in a list using list indices in jinja2

Tags: ansible, jinja2

Using Linux server with installed versions of ansible 2.7.5 .

I was trying to insert the values in list based on their indices but unable to do so.

Could anyone please suggest any solution.

Thanks in advance.

So far, I'm trying with the below code.

**In status variable will be having dictionary values like below.**

```
[{u'CACHE01': True}, {u'CACHE07': False}, {u'CACHE06': False}, {u'CACHE03': True}, {u'CACHE05': False}, {u'CACHE02': True}]

{% set T = 0 %}
{% set F = 1 %}
{% set b = [] %}
{% for i in status %}
{% for k,v in i.items() %}
{% if v == True %}
{{ b.insert(T,k) }}
{% set T = T+2 %}
{% else %}
{{ b.insert(F,k) }}
{% set F = F+2 %}
{% else %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**Result,which I'm getting is:**

```
[CACHE01,CACHE03,CACHE02,CACHE07,CACHE06,CACHE05]
```

**I expect the following results.**

**'b' list should contain values like below. List should contain values like True,False,True,False---etc.**

```
[CACHE01,CACHE07,CACHE03,CACHE06,CACHE02,CACHE05]
```

Answer (score 0):

Variable *status* is a list and must be iterated. The playbook below

```
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    status:
      - CACHE01: True
      - CACHE07: False
      - CACHE06: False
      - CACHE03: True
      - CACHE05: False
      - CACHE02: True
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_keys: "{{ my_keys|default([]) + item.keys() }}"
      loop: "{{ status }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_keys
```

gives:

```
"my_keys": [
    "CACHE01", 
    "CACHE07", 
    "CACHE06", 
    "CACHE03", 
    "CACHE05", 
    "CACHE02"
]
```

To get the list of values. Exchange *item.keys()* for *item.values()*

```
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_values: "{{ my_values|default([]) + item.values() }}"
      loop: "{{ status }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_values
```

Bonus:

To select positive status use filter [bool_and](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56395331/how-to-extract-values-from-list-of-dictionary)

```
$ cat filter_plugins/bool_utils.py
def bool_and(h):
    return all(h)
def bool_or(h):
    return any(h)
class FilterModule(object):
    ''' utility filters for operating on list of Boolean '''
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'bool_and' : bool_and
            ,'bool_or' : bool_or
        }
```

The task below

```
- set_fact:
    my_keys1: "{{ my_keys1|default([]) + item.keys() }}"
  loop: "{{ status }}"
  when: item.values()|bool_and
- debug:
    var: my_keys1
```

gives:

```
"my_keys1": [
    "CACHE01", 
    "CACHE03", 
    "CACHE02"
]
```

Comment: Hi Vladimir,
I want to keep the values in dict format only.
[{'CACHE01': True}, {'CACHE07': False}, {'CACHE06': False}, {'CACHE03': True}, {'CACHE05': False}, {'CACHE02': True}]
And also want to take the values (True and False) in same list not in the separate list.
the list should be like a pair of true and false values.
[CACHE01,CACHE07,CACHE03,CACHE06,CACHE02,CACHE05]

Comment: Just change *keys()" to "values()". I've updated the answer.

Comment: bool_and filter doesn't support in my server.
The conditional check 'item.values()|bool_and' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: no filter named 'bool_and'. String: {% if item.values()|bool_and %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}

Could you please suggest any other.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Or follow the link to review more details. See other [plugins](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-plugins) and how-to [install](https://galaxy.ansible.com/vbotka/ansible) them.